# Ubuntu 14.04.3 Grub detects Windows 10 as Recovery Mode only

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I had installed the brand-new Windows 10 on my PC. Next, I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.3. After using Boot-Repair to fix Ubuntu boot, it seems that Grub always detects the Windows 10 as recovery mode although I still can boot my Windows 10 up via that recovery mode menu entry.

Could anyone please guide me fix this grub issue ?
Thanks,

Comment: Are you repairing the boot by auto mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing you should worry about !

GRUB detects all boot loaders ... the first Windows boot loader detected was the one that points to the **Windows Recovery Environment**.

The "complete" **Windows Boot Environment** will be started when you select Windows Recovery Environment from GRUB menu entries.

So it is just a misleading "wrong" name.

Comment: Yes, I know it's just wrong name because Windows still boots well. I asked this question if anyone can fix Grub to display the entry name correctly as normal. Thanks.

Comment: @HungNguyen : You can edit and change the name in /boot/grub/grub.cfg ... but after every update-grub you'll have to change it again ... this is why I did not include it in my answer ! But If you really want to do it nevertheless you can install gksu (sudo apt-get install gksu) and open the file with gedit as root : gksudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg ... change the name ... save the file ... and after every grub update ... repeat it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry to 40_custom in `/etc/grub.d/` directory, with the entry
that update-grub generated suitably edited to reflect that you really
are booting the real Windows installation.